# Very simple email validation, need to make sure that there are 2 or more characters after the LAST period

Tags: regex, firebase

the program I'm using has its own email validation built in and it only accept emails where the last group of characters after the LAST period is 2 or more. I have this regex statement so far:

```
/^[^@]+@[^@]+\\.[^@]+$/i
```

This is acceptable for what I'm trying to do, not trying to be super fancy here. Just want to check:

- There is an @ sign with something before it that is not an @ sign
- There is something before the last .
- There are at least 2 characters after the last .

I'm just not sure how to test for the LAST . as opposed to ANY . after the @ sign.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can impose this check at the beginning with a positive look-ahead:

```
/^(?=.*\.[^.]{2,}$)[^@]+@[^@]+\.[^@]+$/i
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/qQ9eZ2/1)

The `(?=.*\.[^.]{2,}$)` look-ahead will find the last `.` and then will try to match 2 or more characters other than a dot before the end of string. If there is fewer (just 1) the match will be failed (there will be no match).

**UPDATE**

As you might be unable to use the regex having `^`/`$` anchors in other places than start/end of string, here is another solution:

```
^[^@]+@[^@]+\.[^@.]{2,}$
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/qQ9eZ2/2)

Regex breakdown:

- `^` - start of string
- `[^@]+` - 1 or more characters other than `@`
- `@` - literal `@` symbol
- `[^@]+` - 1 or more characters other than `@` as many as possible (thus, no `ee@.dd` is possible)
- `\.` - a literal dot
- `[^@.]{2,}` - 2 or more characters other than `@` and `.` up to...
- `$` - end of string

Comment: This is working fine in my browser but with the server that I am using that accepts "javascript-like" regex expressions it gives me this error: "illegal regular expression, unescaped ^, ^ can only appear at the end of regular expressions" any idea what this means? Does it not support look-aheads maybe? I will accept as correct answer anyways because it works for my browser :-) Thank you

Comment: I have never heard of this error, but I remember that in some environments `^` is used for escaping. What is the server? I could not google out anything for *^ can only appear at the end of regular expressions* :(

Comment: I am using Firebase and writing the server rules for what is allowed as inputs for email addresses. ^ is used for escaping? Hmm.. I will check if this is the case with Firebase.

Comment: Ah I see this in their guide: "^ and $ anchors only work if we're using them to match the first or last character in the pattern".. I am not sure if this is the issue though.

Comment: Please have a look at the update. It is possible without the lookahead.

Comment: Yes it was the lookahead that was causing the issue. Thank you so much! This works perfectly!!!! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
^[^@]+@[^@]+\.([^@.]{2,})$
```

You can test it here: https://regex101.com/r/eK6fT4/1

Essential part is `[^@.]`: check that end of the string, that doesn't include `@` and `.` is more than 2 characters.

Comment: This accepts this email as correct: "email@test.c.c" I've recently discovered that some emails have two periods at the end, something like "email@test.group.edu" and this is breaking my regex, so I need to find the last occurrence of a period, I believe!